# Italicize labels of only one legend in ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend, typography

I am trying to format a plot with two separate legends on the side. I have a shape legend, for all my different taxa, and a color legend, for the categories they belong in. I want to italicize only the taxon names in the shape legend, and not italicize the category names in the color legend. So far I can make all legend entries italicized or not using this line:

```
plot + theme(legend.text = element_text(face = "italic"))
```

But I don't know how to specify the shape legend only. I don't think `theme()` is appropriate because it changes the theme of the entire plot. I also looked into `guides()` but it doesn't seem to have an option for specifying font face of the legend labels.

Some sample data and a plot:

```
species <- c("M. mulatta", "P. ursinus", "C. mitis", "C. guereza")
subfam <- c("Cercopithecine", "Cercopithecine", "Cercopithecine", "Colobine")
x <- rnorm(4, 1:10)
y <- rnorm(4, 2:20)
df <- data.frame(cbind(species, subfam, x, y))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point(aes(shape = species, color = subfam), size = 4) +
  labs(shape = "Species", color = "Subfamily")
```

In sum, I would like to make the species names italicized but not the subfamily names. It seems like it should be simple... Is this even possible in ggplot?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is quite difficult, involving the manipulation of the raw graphical objects (grobs) before plotting. I'd be inclined to use facets for subfamily and color for species, thus generating only one legend: `library(tidyverse); df %>% rename(Species = species, Subfamily = subfam) %>% ggplot(aes(x, y)) + geom_point(aes(color = Species)) + facet_wrap(~Subfamily) + theme(legend.text = element_text(face = "italic"))`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can customize labels specifically for the `shape` legend, by setting `element_text` parameters, including font, in `scale_shape_discrete`*.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = species, color = subfam), size = 4) +
  labs(shape = "Species", color = "Subfamily") +
  scale_shape_discrete(guide =
                         guide_legend(label.theme = element_text(angle = 0, face = "italic")))
```

[image]

---

*This method also works with `scale_shape_manual`, which also has a `guide` argument. See `?scale_shape` and `?scale_shape_manual`.

---

For some reason I needed to specify `angle` in `element_text`, otherwise it errored. You may also need to set `size`.

Comment: This is a great solution! Unfortunately, there's another component in my real data that I didn't anticipate affecting the solution and so didn't include it in my original question.  I actually have 22 taxa, and scale_shape_discrete() only allows up to 6 different shapes. I originally had scale_shape_manual() to specify the 22 shapes (which I think are perfectly discernible), but the two calls don't work together to produce the desired results.  Any thoughts on how to make them both work? Thanks~

Comment: In `ggplot` you can only have one call to `scale_xxx` per `aes`thetic. Thus, in you case you need to replace `scale_shape_discrete` with `scale_shape_manual`, which takes the same arguments, including `guide`.

Comment: I had tried to add the manual shape values to scale_shape_discrete which didn't work; I forgot to consider the alternative of specifying guide in scale_shape_manual.  Works perfectly, thank you!