# Barchart: italics in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to keep the first label in the legend plain whilst converting the rest into italics, but I don't know how to do this. The code I'm using is:

```
ggplot(the_data_mod) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Protein, y = Protein_Abundance, fill = Mutant), 
           stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(), col = "white") + 
  theme_minimal()+   
  labs(title = "Relative Levels of TOC Protein Abundance across SP2 Mutants", 
       x = "Protein")+
  ylab(expression(atop("Protein Abundance", paste("(Normalised Relative to WT)"))))
```

and the data is:

```
structure(list(Mutant = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("WT", "ppi1", "sp2-4", "sp2-1 ppi1", "sp2-3 ppi1", "sp2-5 ppi1", "sp2-6 ppi1", "sp2-8 ppi1"), class = "factor"), Protein = c("TOC75", "TOC75", "TOC75", "TOC75", "TOC75", "TOC75", "TOC75", "TOC75", "TOC159", "TOC159", "TOC159", "TOC159", "TOC159", "TOC159", "TOC159", "TOC159" ), Protein_Abundance = c(100, 19.79, 209.85, 364.6, 183.14, 435.02, 22.23, 109.79, 100, 39.52, 266.72, 88.66, 105.04, 132.01, 99.7, 140.1349751)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Comment: Could you possibly use `dput(the_data_mod)` and post the output please? It's very difficult to read in your sample data

Comment: structure(list(Mutant = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("WT", "ppi1", 
"sp2-4", "sp2-1 ppi1", "sp2-3 ppi1", "sp2-5 ppi1", "sp2-6 ppi1", 
"sp2-8 ppi1"), class = "factor"), Protein = c("TOC75", "TOC75", 
"TOC75", "TOC75", "TOC75", "TOC75", "TOC75", "TOC75", "TOC159", 
"TOC159", "TOC159", "TOC159", "TOC159", "TOC159", "TOC159", "TOC159"
), Protein_Abundance = c(100, 19.79, 209.85, 364.6, 183.14, 435.02, 
22.23, 109.79, 100, 39.52, 266.72, 88.66, 105.04, 132.01, 99.7, 
140.1349751)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))

Comment: You have asked [a very similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59554096/ggplot2-italics-in-the-legend)  It would be generally appreciated if you would point to previous questions of similar (in this case: the same!) gist, so that the people who help you have it easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code for that

```
  ggplot(the_data_mod, aes(x = Protein, y = Protein_Abundance, fill = Mutant)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(), col = "white") +
  scale_fill_discrete("Mutant",
                      labels = c(expression(italic("ppi1")), 
                                 expression(italic("sp2-1 ppi1")),
                                 expression(italic("sp2-3 ppi1")),
                                 expression(italic("sp2-4")),
                                 expression(italic("sp2-5 ppi1")), 
                                 expression(italic("sp2-6 ppi1")),
                                 expression(italic("sp2-8 ppi1")),
                                 expression(italic("WT")))) + 
  theme_minimal()+  
  theme(legend.text.align = 0)+  
  labs(title = "Relative Levels of TOC Protein Abundance across SP2 Mutants", 
       x = "Protein")+
  ylab(expression(atop("Protein Abundance", paste("(Normalised Relative to WT)"))))
```

[image]

Comment: [here is a function which helps avoid typing out all those expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44661732/7941188).

Comment: there is an even easier option - see my answer

Answer (score 2):

- If your aim is to italicise all your legend labels, you can simply use `theme`.
- If you have several legends and only want to italicise one of them, you can specify this with the `guide` argument in your `scale` calls (see below, Credit to @Henrik 's [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48572994/7941188))
- If you only want to italicise certain categories, either use @BappaDas option or use @MrFlicks function [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44661732/7941188) (you can tweak the `ifelse` statement within the function)

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Easiest option

ggplot(the_data_mod) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Protein, y = Protein_Abundance, fill = Mutant), 
           stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(), col = "white") + 
  theme(legend.text = element_text(face = "italic"))

# or (for the case of several legends)

ggplot(the_data_mod) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Protein, y = Protein_Abundance, fill = Mutant), 
           stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(), col = "white") + 
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = guide_legend(label.theme = element_text(angle = 0, face = "italic")))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>